# HP Proliant ML350 G6 Power backplane diagonsis

Tags: hp-proliant, electrical-power

I get no lights at all.

I am looking for some sort of testing procedure on the board level as I am not sure if the issue IS power plane related, or if it is just a bad main board.

the power supply works when plugged into a breakout board [I have not load tested] (https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07C6LTPWT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I get no green light with the PSU plugged in outside of the server

I get no green light (from the PSU) when inserted into the server and plugged in (left it overnight)

No lights anywhere, even after being plugged in over night

I would like to test that the power back plane is functioning correctly, because I'm not interested in spending 150 Canadian rupees on something I can't test.

Is there a way to get a green light on the PSU without the mainboard, I can use a mutlimeter, I just have no idea where to start or how to find board diagrams

- ! _ [UPDATE] _ ! -

> @KingDunken
>
> PSU gives me a green light when shorted

Is there any way to test the mid-plane without the mainboard, to figure out if the mainboard is bad

Comment: As someone who has some hardware design for our Proliant servers, the power supply's green light only turns on when you plug it into the midplane (in the chassis slot for the PSU). The green light won't come on if you have it turned on outside of the chassis unless you short circuit some the gold fingers together. I would only do this if you know how to get the solder off. If you look at the PSU with the gold fingers facing towards you, on the left you should see individual pins and then two really long pins on the right side. If you short the first and fourth pin...

Comment: [continued] on the left side then you should see power when you plug in the power supply to the wall and you don't have to put it in the chassis for this to work. See [this picture](https://blog.seidel-philipp.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/hp-dps-1200fb-netzteil-umbauen_power_supply_hack_wiring.jpg) to see what I'm talking about. Short pin 33 and pin 36. If you power supply green light doesn't turn on, then there's something wrong with the power supply.

Comment: I just saw your update. Please reply in the comments with `@KingDuken` so that I get notified when you're talking to me. So to answer your question about testing the midplane, the customer would/should never go out of their way to troubleshoot hardware issues. Contact our sales and see if they can forward your inquiry to an engineer and they will help you troubleshoot. The ML team would help you out. It is very probable that something is definitely wrong with the midplane because you just indicated that the PSU still works.

Comment: @KingDuken

I am not interested in paying $3000 for a service plan to have HPE tell me to buy a new something. I am confident enough to find controllers and caps and replace them at board level. I was hoping this older hardware would have diagrams somewhere

Comment: @KingDuken

I am currently trying to source a replacement bios chip, as while doing some more poking around, realized I had put the bios battery in reverse polarity.

I Sould still like to test the power plane to see if I am ordering a new mainboard AND a power plane